# Why does the smarthome testsuite fail?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I was trying to run the smart home test suite for my test TV device. Traits onOff works fine with Google Home and Google Assistant. But if i run the test suite for the same device.

Followed the instructions given in the link:
https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/develop/testing-submitting

I am getting the below error:
AssertionError: Expected state to include: {"on":true}, actual state: {}: expected false to be true
Ok Google. Turn on the Media room TV (manual) ‣
AssertionError: expected false to be true

additional info: Report State also implemented. But the onOff traits not reaching the fulfillment.

Comment: Please edit this question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") should include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: hi Max, The desired behavior should be onOff Traits should reach the fulfillment and also the smart home test suite should pass. when i start the smart home test suite for my device. The problems are 1. The intent did not reach my fulfillment. 2. i am getting an error in the smart home test suite: Expected state to include: {"on":true}, actual state: {}: expected false to be true Ok Google. Turn on the Media room TV (manual) ‣ AssertionError: expected false to be true

Comment: For the problem #1: While running the test suite, the PC should be unmuted, so that the Google Assistant supported device will listen the commands from test suite and sends the intent. #2. Report State implementation is must when we send the SYNC Response to GA with willReportState as true. The above issue is not seen now. Please refer for more detailed explanation : https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/develop/report-state

Answer (score 0):

This kind of an error on test suite indicates that your report state does not reach Google servers in a reliable fashion. The test result indicates it is looking for an "on":true case written to Homegraph, but it cannot find your reported state change.

You can verify if your reported state changes are reaching Homegraph by using [Home Graph Viewer](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/tools/home-graph-viewer).